# Does the command "git reset --hard <commit>" remove commit history in another branch?

Tags: git, git-reset

Let's say I made `a, b, c, d` commits so far. I'm currently in `d` and I want to go back to `a`.

`a` and `d` are in `master` branch. `b` and `c` are `temp` branch.

In this case, if I run `git reset --hard <a's commit>`, will I lose the commit `b` and `c` because they are made after `a`? Is it true even though they are in another branch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The commit history of the other branch (`temp`) will not be altered if you run your `reset` command while on the `master` branch.

The `reset` command actually will never delete a commit or change the content of a branch that you do not have currently checked out. It is just simply moving your `HEAD` pointer around.

A very useful tool that is worth mentioning is the [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog). Every time you create a commit (or the tip of a branch is updated) an entry is stored in the reflog. You can see the contents of the reflog with: `git reflog`.

So, if you ever feel that you've "lost" a commit, you can search for it in the reflog and cherry-pick it back.

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/523963/how-can-i-revert-back-to-a-git-commit), I saw someone's answer saying `A note of warning that git reset will alter history -- if I made several commits and then reset to the first commit, the subsequent commits will no longer be in the commit history.` So, I thought I might lose everything after the commit that I wanna go back to. Is he wrong?

Comment: You will "lose" the commits on the branch that you are currently one (but your other branches will remain untouched)...but in reality those commits are easy to get back if you need them by locating your previous point in the reflog and using `reset --hard` to go back to that point

Comment: Understood! Thank you